# Is it possible to decode an HTTP/x image stream using OpenCv?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm exploring some optimizations for an image processing RPC implemented in `Python`. We currently read the image into memory from a `http GET` request and then process with `OpenCv`. We would instead like to stream the image and process its chunks.

We currently do something like this.

```
data = requests.get(url).content
arr = np.fromstring(data, np.uint8)
img = cv2.imdecode(arr)
process_img_with_opencv(img)
```

We would instead like to do something like this.

```
stream = get_img_stream(url)
img = cv2.imdecode(stream)
process_img(img)
# or perhaps process_img_stream(stream)
```

I would think there ought to be some way to implement this, though I'm a bit concerned it might involve writing to disk in between? In our use case, that might still improve throughput. Is this possible?

Comment: no, imdecode needs all the data at once. you are getting no real speed benefit by trying to decode the picture before the entire file has been received. nor would you gain any improved memory footprint because the decoded bitmap is always the largest object and storing the encoded file in memory for a split second can't possibly be a concern. in any case, decoding an image file into a bitmap (np.array) takes little enough time that optimizing *this* is misguided. you should use a profiler to figure out where your server's time is spent.

Comment: if you ***really*** require streamed decoding, you'll have to talk **directly** to the corresponding libraries (libjpeg, libpng, ...). they'll allow you to specify callbacks that get individual image rows or bands as soon as the data has been decoded. still, there's no great benefit to progressive decoding because your `process_img` surely needs the entire picture at once, yes?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz In this particular use case, I actually would only ever need to have one pixel in memory at time for that process image method to work. Obviously file formats make this a bit more complicated. In general, I don't see why having a stream abstraction of something that potentially uses significant memory would **not** be a benefit.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz By the way, it's not a speed optimization I'm after. Or at least not one that's measurable outside of heavy load scenarios. It's a memory optimization.

Comment: if you're after memory optimization, then you must care about _every step_. image decoding and encoding would have to be able to do this. OpenCV is made for computer vision, not for maximal control over image de/compression. since you desire full control over image encoding/decoding, you must use those libraries directly.

Answer (score 0):

For now, I've decided to keep it simple and go with `r.raw.read()`. This pattern is pretty common throughout or codebase, and Python the community. I know the `raw.read()` generator does a pretty good job of keeping chunks out of memory. But, I still would curious if there's a better way to do this.

```
r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
arr = np.frombuffer(r.raw.read(), np.uint8)
bgr = cv2.imdecode(arr, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
img = cv2.cvtColor(bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
process_img(img)
```

Comment: this is **functionally identical** (raw.read()/content, frombuffer/fromstring) to what you already had in your question, apart from the suddenly introduced cvtColor that was *not* part of the requirement.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz  is it? I thought `Response.raw.read()` is the iterator which enables `iter_content.` The response library itself describes as `iter_content` as "avoiding loading the entire response into [Python] memory."

Comment: show me what `.raw.read()` returns. what type is the result? you didn't use iter_anything, you used `.raw.read()` -- in any case, what do you think np.frombuffer would do with an iterator from `iter_content`? it's gonna make a zero-dimensional array of `dtype=object` that simply contains the unconsumed iterator

Comment: If you follow the links from [here](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/urllib3.response.html#urllib3.response.HTTPResponse.read), I believe it’s similar to BufferedIOBase, but it’s not well documented.

Comment: that's documentation for urllib3, not requests, and that documentation does not state the type of the return value. -- I'm not asking because I want to know or have any doubts about what's happening. I'm asking to get you to find out. -- the `read()` call will return the entire response payload as a bytes object or something equivalent.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz that’s what it is. `urllib3` objects underly lots of `requests`. See [here](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/)

Comment: Yeah, reifying the generator as a numpy array immediately after concerns me. But, in the least, I get to keep a one of these large objects out of memory. If I really wanted to avoid that, I suppose I could use something like dask or indeed write my own stream processor.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz  I just profiled the two above [here](https://gist.github.com/l-monninger/005924f75ef8834c92ca91acdf24e687). But, now I'm very suspicious about what's going with this object because, in some cases, the stream version is not reporting significant memory increments at all.